# Print ActiveSheet single sided

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to print an `ActiveSheet` single sided and two sided. The two sided print (`Case Dubbelzijdig`) and the `Case Concept` are working fine. How to make the `Case Origineel` print the `ActiveSheet` single sided. Which values to pass to `.PrintOut`?

```
Option Explicit
Private bActive As Boolean

Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    Dim WordRange As Range

With ActiveSheet

    Select Case lstSelect

    Case "Concept"

        .ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True

    Case "Origineel"

        .PrintOut

    Case "Dubbelzijdig"

        .PrintOut , , , , ActivePrinter

    End Select
End With

Unload frmSelect
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
  While bActive
    DoEvents
  Wend

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  bActive = True
  With lstSelect
    .AddItem "Concept"
    .AddItem "Origineel"
    .AddItem "Dubbelzijdig"
    If .ListCount > 0 Then
      lstSelect = lstSelect.Column(0, 0)
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You probably can't just with `.PrintOut` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/ff838253.aspx . I haven't a clue to help you at the moment, but google *Excel VBA print single side* and you should have matches that help! ;)

Comment: I already looked at the page you linked. I googled my question but I'am not able to fix my problem.